# Writing a function that returns the number of unique names in a column in a dataset - Python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a function that takes an integer a dataset (one that I already have, named `data`). And looks for a column in this dataset called `name`. It then has to return the number of different types of names there are in the column (there are 4 values, but only 3 types of values--two of them are the same).

I'm having a hard time with this program, but this is what I have so far:

```
def name_count(data):
    unique = []
    for name in data:
        if name.strip() not in unique:
            unique[name] += 1
        else:
            unique[name] = 1
            unique.append(name)
```

The only import I'm allowed to use for this challenge is `math`.

Does anyone have any help or advice they can offer with this problem?

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset

Comment: `id,name,level,personality,type,weakness,atk,def,hp,stage
59,Arcanine,35,impish,fire,water,50,55,90,2
59,Arcanine,35,gentle,fire,water,45,60,80,2
121,Starmie,67,sassy,water,electric,174,56,113,2
131,Lapras,72,lax,water,electric,107,113,29,1`

Comment: As far I understand you want to have the unique values of the column name.
You can do it like this: data['name'].nunique()

Comment: @BillyBonaros Without Pandas?

Comment: Are your data in a Pandas Dataframe format?

Comment: len(set(data['name']))

Comment: Can you provide the sample data into your post, please? So we can have better visualisation of your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `set` to keep duplicates from it, for example:

```
data = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name3   ']

cleaned_data = map(lambda x: x.strip(), data)
count = len(set(cleaned_data))

print(count)
>>> 3
```

Comment: Hmm when I run this, I'm getting 5 as a result. I'm assuming that is because there is 5 lines in this dataset. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: u can `print` the resulting `set` and check where your error is. like `print(set(cleaned_data))`. remember that `data` is a `list` with the names, it doesn't include other fields.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.  Unique should be a dictionary, not a list.

```
def name_count(data):
    unique = {}
    for name in data:
        if name.strip()  in unique:
            unique[name] += 1
        else:
            unique[name] = 1
    return unique

#test
print(name_count(['Jack', 'Jill', 'Mary', 'Sam', 'Jack', 'Mary']))

#output
{'Jack': 2, 'Jill': 1, 'Mary': 2, 'Sam': 1}
```

Comment: Hmm when I run this it doesn't return anything... Am I perhaps missing something here??

Comment: @jen_hen1    As long as you have your data as a list, this function will return a dictionary with the count of each name.  See the test I added to the code.

Comment: I'm looking to just return an integer of the number of names. So for your example, the output would be 4 because there are 4 different types of names.

Comment: If that's what you want, it's very simple.  Instead of return unique, write return len(unique) in the last line of the code.  It gives you the length of the dictionary which is the same as the number of unique names, 4.

Comment: Hmm so this is what I have at the moment, but it's still not returning anything. `def name_count(data):
    unique = {}
    for name in data:
        if name.strip() in unique:
            unique[name] += 1
        else:
            unique[name] = 1
    return len(unique)
`

Comment: I have tested it multiple times.  Are you feeding it a list? What list? Do you have your indentation right.  Copy and paste my code to help troubleshoot yours.

Comment: @jen_hen1. Also make sure you say print(name_count()) not just name_count() so that you print the returned value of the function.

Comment: I'm feeding it a csv that is saved to a variable named `data`. So I made it so the function can accept `file_name` and then I input `data` when running the function. I also tried it so the function takes in `data` directly. Both ways, I haven't had any results.

Comment: I finally got it to go but it's still returning with 5, rather than 3 like expected...

Comment: @jen_hen1.  I see now, This function was designed to take in a list of pure names, nothing else.  See my new answer for csv file,

Comment: I wish I could use it, but like I mentioned in my original poster, I can't use any imports asides from `math`... :(

Comment: I added an addendum to my other answer that uses a text file reader and does not requires any imports.

Comment: I'm now trying to complete this challenge only using Pandas. Do you know how I should go about doing this??

Comment: First you need to accept one of the answers to your original question and upvote all the people who have worked hard to help you. Then, I recommend that you repost your question, specifically asking how to solve it with Pandas. Make sure you first make an attempt to solve it on your own, present whatever code you have, and clearly describe your input and expected output on your next post and all future posts. You can leave me a comment on this thread when you have you have posted your next question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def name_count(data):
  df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
  unique = []
  for name in df["name"]:  #if column name is "name"
    if name:
      if (name not in unique) :
        unique.append(name)
  return unique
```

You need to pass the complete dataset to the function and not just the integers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you are feeding a csv file to your function. It reads the csv file, gets rid of the header line, accumulates the names which are on index 1 of each line, casts the list as a set to get rid of the duplicates and returns the length of the set which is the same as the number of unique names.

```
import csv
def name_count(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        names = [row[1] for row in csvreader if row][1:]
        return len(set(names))
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a csv reader, you can use a tect file reader without any imports as follows.  The code splits each line on commas.

```
def name_count(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as input:
        names = [row.rstrip('\n').split(',')[1] for row in input if row][1:]
        return len(set(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what kind of `data` variable you already have there.

So, I will suggest a solution, starting from reading the file.
Considering that you have a csv file and that there is a restriction on importing only `math` module (as you mentioned), then this should work.

```
def name_count(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        headers = next(fh).split(',')
        name_col_idx = headers.index('name')
        names = [
            line.split(',')[name_col_idx]
            for line in fh
        ]
        return len(set(names))
```

Here we read the first line, identify the location of `name` in the header, collect all items in the `name` column into a variable `names` and finally return the length of the set, which contains only unique elements.